Convert pint-panda dataframe to numpy
I have a large dataframe (>30 000 rows and > 500 columns), I am using pint to convert from one unit to another using the pint-panda option then I wish to write the dataframe to a text file. I have up to 20 000 text files to write.
However, I couldn't find in the pint documentation how to "remove" the pint layer once the conversion is done.
For speed reasons I am using np.savetxt() rather than a panda solution. To that end, I first convert my dataframe to float df.astype(float) and then apply the desired float formating in the text file.

np.savetxt(   file,   output_data.astype(float),  header=header_out,
delimiter="",   fmt="%-15.5e",  comments="", )

However doing that generates as many warning messages as there are columns: UnitStrippedWarning: The unit of the quantity is stripped when downcasting to ndarray
I am using an ugly workaround warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") to avoid being spammed but it is not the best solution.
Using df.to_numpy() yields a pint Quantity object which is incompatible with the float foramting in np.savetxt.
How could I convert my dataframe to float without generating all those warning messages ? Or remove the pint effect on my data ?

Where did you learn that savetxt would be faster than some pint/pandas alternative?

After digging even more, it turns out that the pint-pandas package had a recent update. The warning message mentioned has been removed from v0.6.

To remove the pint layer from your dataframe and convert it to a float without generating warnings, you can iterate over the columns of your dataframe and extract the magnitude of each pint Quantity:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pint ##pip install pint
import warnings

# Create a UnitRegistry
ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()
Q_ = ureg.Quantity

# Sample dataframe with pint quantities
data = {'length': [Q_(1.5, 'meter'), Q_(2.0, 'meter')], 'weight': [Q_(3.0, 'kilogram'), Q_(4.0, 'kilogram')]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Function to remove pint quantities and get magnitudes
def remove_pint_quantities(df):
    new_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for col in df.columns:
        new_df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: x.magnitude if isinstance(x, Q_) else x)
    return new_df

# Remove pint quantities
df_magnitude = remove_pint_quantities(df)

# Convert to numpy array
output_data = df_magnitude.to_numpy()

# Define header
header_out = "length          weight"

# Save to text file without warnings
np.savetxt('output.txt', output_data.astype(float), header=header_out, delimiter=" ", fmt="%-15.5e", comments="")


Thansk for that, I didn't want to go through that route since it can bequite time consuming to iterate over a very large dataframe. It is however answering my question! Luckily, a simple package update was only needed.
